# NameError in Python - suptitle not defined

Tags: python, matplotlib, suptitle

```
fig = suptitle('image #{}'.format(num), fontsize=20)
NameError: name 'suptitle' is not defined
```

I already installed numpy, scipy and matplotlib and imported pylab but for some reason Python isn't recognizing the suptitle function.

Comment: is `suptitle` a misspelling of `subtitle`?

Comment: Well, did you define or import suptitle? Where? Show that part of the code.

Comment: 'import pylab
import imageio
import suptitle
myFilename = r'\Windows\video.mp4'
vid = imageio.get_reader(myFilename, 'ffmpeg')
nums = [10, 287]
for num in nums:
    image = vid.get_data(num)
    fig = pylab.figure()
    fig = suptitle('image #{}'.format(num), fontsize=20)
    pylab.imshow(image)
pylab.show()'

Comment: Python in general can only use functions that have been imported previously. It seems you want to use matplotlib pyplot's `suptitle` function here, so you may import it as `from matplotlib.pyplot import suptitle`. If you do so, the code you show will not produce any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.suptitle('image #{}'.format(num), fontsize = 20)
```